# Is destiny bond a priority move?

Tags: pokemon-series

I am in the process of building a troll Wobafet, and I want him to know destiny bond for obvious reasons. Is this move a priority move? Or do I have to go first naturally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. [Destiny Bond](http://serebii.net/attackdex-xy/destinybond.shtml) has a [normal priority](http://www.smogon.com/bw/moves/destiny_bond), so it will go *after* priority moves, and before or after other normal priority based on the pokemon's speed and other factors (Trick Room, etc).

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answer stated, Destiny Bond is not a priority move under normal conditions. However, there are some shenanigans you can do to make it so with Wobbuffet<sup>1</sup>.

Destiny Bond is considered a status move, so it can be become a priority move by having the ability [Prankster](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Prankster_(Ability)). While in double battles, you need a secondary Pokemon with the ability Prankster who can learn the move Skill Swap ([Male Mewostic](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Meowstic_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) is the only who can do this in Gen 8).

By having Male Mewostic use Skill Swap on Wobbufett, your troll can now use Destiny Bond as a priory move.

---

<sup>1</sup> If your troll set up requires Wobbuffet to know either of it's abilities (Shadowtag or Telepathy) or if you are in single battles, it won't work.

Comment: Just Telepathy. Shadow Tag only prevents the opponent from switching, with can be really annoying when they ***have*** to kill Wobbuffet to pass (i.e. your Meowstic knows the move Protect and Protects every other turn). Telepathy will not work because then Wobbuffet is immune to Skill Swap.

Comment: @EmCeeChupirelDreemurr [Telepathy](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Telepathy_(Ability)#In_battle) only affects damaging moves from your ally; you are still "vulnerable" to status moves

Comment: Well, I didn't know that. Should have looked it up on Bulbapedia. Mainly because I only knew about the ability from my Sun and Moon Playthrough guide.

Answer (score 0):

Like all the above answers have stated, Destiny Bond is a +0 priority under normal conditions, except in the situations above or if Quick Claw activates.

However, Destiny Bond has a unique effect in that it does **not** last until the turn it was used ends, but rather the end of your *next* turn, but they'll probably K.O. Wobbuffet before then, so if Wobbuffet lives the first hit and doesn't regain enough HP to survive the next hit, it will faint and Destiny Bond will activate, taking down the opposing Pokemon as well.